# Angular6 Can't use ternary operator in ngClass with multiple entries

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-ng-class

I'm trying to add multiple classes by ngClass, and I'm confused as to why I can't use ternary operator here.

```
<div [ngClass]="{'otherClass': otherFlag, classFlag ? 'class--true': 'class--false'}>
```

I get the following error:

```
Parser Error: Missing expected } at column 37 in [{'otherClass': otherFlag, classFlag ? 'class--true': 'class--false'}]
```

I'm aware I can do the following:

```
<div [ngClass]="{
'otherClass': otherFlag,
'class--true': classFlag,
'class--false': !classFlag
}">
```

Just trying to understand why I can't use ternary operator here (or maybe I'm doing it wrong). I would appreciate the help in understanding this.

Edit: Thank you for both answers. I mostly understood it thanks to Bryan's answer, but both were helpful.

Comment: What you have is simply an invalid JavaScript consturct. As your other example shows you need to have an object, and while you can make an expression with a ternary operator that results in an object, your other example is simpler and  more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use ternary operator this way because the value of `ngClass` is a JavaScript object and your class name is used as a key of the object. The ternary operator can only be used for values, not for keys.

You **can** do this in a JSON:

```js
{
 "key": condition ? value : otherValue
}
```

But you **can't** do that:

```js
{
 condition ? "key" : "otherKey": value
}
```

To do what you want to do you have to use `[class]` instead of `[ngCLass]`. Like that:

```html
<div [class]="classFlag ? 'class--true' : 'class--false'">
```

Answer (score 0):

They just can't be combined in that way. Use one or the other. For multi condition use example 3, for tenerary use example 1 or 2.

```html
<div [ngClass]="classFlag === false ? 'class--true' : 'class--false'">
  I will be class false
</div>

<div [ngClass]="classFlag === true ? 'class--true' : 'class--false'">
I will be class true
</div>

<div [ngClass]="{ otherClass: otherFlag === true }">I will be class true</div>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hmnctu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html